# Retrieving data from a JSON sub array in javascript, where identifier starts with an integer

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, identifier

I must be missing something simple here, but I'm having trouble retrieving data from a JSON array response. I can access objects with identifiers that start with letters, but not ones that start with numbers.

For example, I can access

```
data.item[0].specs.overview.details
```

But I can't access

```
data.item[0].specs.9a99.details
```

Comment: Argh, I should have known this. Thanks for all the quick answers! I'm going to accept the first one.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer.  It's a good way to improve your chances of getting help in the future.

Comment: Yup, I did, but the system won't let me accept answers for 15 minutes after the question is asked. Thanks for the info, though! I also voted up all the answers that were correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [bracket notation](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html#sBs)

that is:

```
data.item[0].specs["9a99"].details
```

Comment: thanks, this is the answer. (I'll check it off as soon as the time limit is passed).

Answer (score 5):

Identifier literals must not begin with a number because they would be confused with number literals. You need to use the bracket syntax in this case:

```
 data.item[0].specs["9a99"].details
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
data.items[0].specs["9a99"].details
```

Answer (score 2):

A variable name in javascript cannot start with a numeral. That's the reason why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript doesn't like variables or identifiers that start with a number, [this reference](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/91400-naming-rules-javascript-html-scripting) states that only:

```
Any variable name has to start with
_ (underscore) 
$ (currency sign) 
a letter from [a-z][A-Z] range 
Unicode letter in the form \uAABB (where AA and BB are hex values)
```

are valid first characters.

Comment: thanks for the additional info. This is helpful and appreciated.